# Converting Json file to Markdown with NodeJs

Tags: json, node.js, markdown

I have a question. I have a JSON file, and I need to convert this file to Markdown format with NodeJs and how I achieve this?

First block title second block code.

I only need `code` blocks:

```
{
    "code": "## Chapter 21 - Dichotomous Predicted Variable",
    "language": "Markdown",
    "index": 0,
    "output": {
        "image/png": "aaaaaaa",
        "text/plain": [
            "<IPython.core.display.Image object>"
        ]
    },
    "created": "2018-8-28 12:03:33",
    "evaluated": true,
    "hiddenCode": false
},
{
    "code": "- [21.1 - Multiple Metric Predictors](#21.1---Multiple-Metric-Predictors)\n- [21.3 - Robust Logistic Regression](#21.3---Robust-Logistic-Regression)\n- [21.4 - Nominal Predictors](#21.4---Nominal-Predictors)",
    "language": "Python",
    "index": 0,
    "output": {
        "image/png": "bbbbb",
        "text/plain": [
            "<IPython.core.display.Image object>"
        ]
    },
    "created": "2018-8-28 12:03:33",
    "evaluated": true,
    "hiddenCode": false
},
```

I want to say that I will print all of them in plain text, and finally I will get the .md output. I will make it out so it will be;

```
if language == Markdown

[21.1 - Multiple Metric Predictors](#21.1---Multiple-Metric-Predictors)\n- [21.3 - Robust Logistic Regression](#21.3---Robust-Logistic-Regression)\n- [21.4 - Nominal Predictors](#21.4---Nominal-Predictors)",


if language === Python

%load std_ipython_import.txt
\nimport pandas as pd\n
import numpy as np\n
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt\n
import seaborn as sns\n
import pymc3 as pm\n
import theano.tensor as tt\n
\nfrom scipy.stats import beta\n
from scipy.special import expit\n
from matplotlib import gridspec\n
from IPython.display import Image\n\n
%matplotlib inline\nplt.style.use('seaborn-white')\n\ncolor = '#87ceeb'\n\nf_dict = {'size':16}",
```

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.

Comment: I edited, I only need code blocks

Comment: What did you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some library to make the conversion. For example `showdown` (http://showdownjs.com). Then it's straightforward, just `map` through the array and convert what you need.

```
// index.js
const showdown = require('showdown')

const json = [
  {
    "code": "## Chapter 21 - Dichotomous Predicted Variable",
    ...
  },
  {
    "code": "- [21.1 - Multiple Metric Predictors](#21.1---Multiple-Metric-Predictors)\n- [21.3 - Robust Logistic Regression](#21.3---Robust-Logistic-Regression)\n- [21.4 - Nominal Predictors](#21.4---Nominal-Predictors)",
    ...
  },
]

const converter = new showdown.Converter()
const result = json.map(item => converter.makeHtml(item.code))

console.log(result)
```

Output:

```
[ 
  '<h2 id="chapter21dichotomouspredictedvariable">Chapter 21 - Dichotomous Predicted Variable</h2>',
  '<ul>\n<li><a href="#21.1---Multiple-Metric-Predictors">21.1 - Multiple Metric Predictors</a></li>\n<li><a href="#21.3---Robust-Logistic-Regression">21.3 - Robust Logistic Regression</a></li>\n<li><a href="#21.4---Nominal-Predictors">21.4 - Nominal Predictors</a></li>\n</ul>' 
]
```

Comment: I want to write in string, not HTML

Comment: @jennifercryt what do you mean by `in string`?